# Add image to Word footer with "In front of text" parameter

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing Word file from Excel using VBA. Current code is able to paste image to footer but it is pasted before texts that I have already in my footer. How to paste with parameters "In front of text"? Ideally I would like to have picture pasted to the most left corner in folder.

Here is my current code:

```
Dim SrcePath As String

SrcePath = "C:\Users\pc\Pictures\signature.png"

Dim t As Long
With WordDoc
  For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
    Set wdRng = .Tables(t).Range.Characters.Last.Next
    If wdRng.End < .Range.End Then
      If wdRng.Text = vbCr Then wdRng.Delete
    End If
  Next
  .TablesOfContents(1).Update
  .Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture (SrcePath)
End With
```

---

**EDIT:**

By in front of text I mean this option:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture (SrcePath)
```

inserts an InlineShape. You need to insert and position a floating Shape. For example:

Replace -

```
Dim t As Long
```

with:

```
Dim t As Long, Shp As Shape, sPosH As Single
```

Replace:

```
.Sections(1).Footers(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture (SrcePath)
```

with:

```
  With .Sections(1).PageSetup
    sPosH = .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin - .Gutter
  End With
  Set Shp = .Sections(1).Footers(1).Shapes.AddPicture(SrcePath, False, True)
  With Shp
    .LockAspectRatio = True
    .Width = Application.InchesToPoints(2)
    .LeftRelative = 0 'wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
    .Left = sPosH - .Width
    .TopRelative = 5 'wdRelativeVerticalPositionBottomMarginArea
    .Top = 0
    .WrapFormat.Type = 6 'wdWrapFront
  End With
```

Note the 'Application.InchesToPoints(2)' line. That allows you to control the picture size via its width. There's a CentimetersToPoints property also, if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you again! Is there any way to insert image "in front the text"? I have tried to add `.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront` inside with block but it looks like `wdWrapFront` is not supported. Your code is working but image is still "In line with text".

Comment: Also tried with enumeration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdwraptype

Comment: @hatman «Your code is working but image is still "In line with text"» False. The code I posted *does not* insert an image in-line with text; only your original code does that. See revised answer for how to change the wrap format, though the only effect of wdWrapFront might be to obscure some of the header content.